# Continuous time markov chain problem from Essentials of Stochastic Processes

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, poisson-process

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbJQQ.png)

I'm stuck on this question, I don't even know where to start here. What is the rate of the prof writing letter when there are less than k requests?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For each $k$, the rate is $2k$. If there is $1$ letter, the rate is $2$; if there are $2$ letters, the rate is $4$, and so on.

Comment: So it's a M/G/1 queueing system.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea I disagree; the rate depends linearly on the amount of letters that have to be written. In fact, that makes it an $M/M/\infty$ system. (Assuming that the processing of the letters is Markovian, which is implied by the word 'rate'.)

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer You are right. It's not.

Comment: Please do not use images to convey information which can be written.  For an explanation, [see here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/).  For help with mathematical formatting, please review the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a single stressed professor processing a letter with rate $2k$, where $k$ is the number of letters that have yet to be processed, you can instead look at the setup as consisting of a team of infinitely many professors, each of them capable of processing a letter with rate $2$. From this point of view, it becomes apparent that you're dealing with an $M / G / \infty$ queueing system. Although the service distribution is never said to be Poisson, the word 'rate' nonetheless makes me suspect that we're in fact looking at an $M/M/\infty$ queue with arrival rate $8$, and service rate $2$.

With this observation, questions (a) and (c) can be tackled with standard tools that I presume you have available.

Unless I misunderstand, with (b) you have to be a bit more careful, because in the translation to the $M/G/\infty$ queue the first-come-first-serve basis gets lost. Question (b), in the language of $M / G / \infty$ queues, becomes the following. Suppose a customer arrives in the $M / G / \infty$ queue and he is the $n$-th customer into the system. Given, then, that there are $n$ customers in the system, what is the expected amount of time for $n$ customers to get served by the system?

Hope this helps. I haven't fact-checked my claims so let me know if something feels off.

Comment: I suggest it's a M/G/$\infty$ queue, since professor does not reply the letters according to a Possion process.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea I thought the same but the word 'rate' made me believe that the services are Markovian as well. Moreover I'm not sure that the questions are easily answerable in the $M/G/\infty$ case in a closed-form manner --- though admittedly I haven't tried. Let me clarify my answer a bit.